# Is 80-90 degrees celsius hot for MBP 2019 CPU temperature

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature

I just converted to apple and bought the latest 16inch MBP with a 6 cores core i7 processor and 16GB of RAM.

I am noticing that it gets hot easily, on idle the temperature is around ~45 degrees celsius and when I have chrome and terminal installing something it can go up to 95 degrees and then goes back to about 50.

I only had the laptop for about a week now, is this normal or should I return it?

Also, I am checking the temperature using istat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked mine, a 2020 16" MBP i5 with 16 GB of RAM and it's running at 83 degrees celsius. So I would say yes, this is normal. I am currently running a Time Machine backup and the fans are running.

You can check the temperature of the CPU die from the Terminal via the `sudo powermetrics | grep -i "CPU die temperature"` command. You will need to kill this with a Control-C command.

Comment: Thanks for the command, I think it might be more accurate than the istat reading.  After doing some research and comparing my temp with other users, I think it is normal.